# Edit Text and Text View not visible when ListView is set in Android

Tags: android, listview, xml-layout

here my xml layout of my Android app (where I show all of my contacts)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent">

   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/android:empty"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
       android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
       android:text="Scegli il contatto:"
         />

   <EditText 
       android:id="@+id/editTextSend"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

   <ListView
       android:id="@+id/android:list"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
   </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

I fill ListView using a custom Adapter. 
But textView and Edit Text are not visibile. I want to show in particular edit text where users can write initial letters of his contacts name) 
Suggestions to get them visible?

Comment: How many values are in your ListView?

Comment: The TextView is not shown because you used the magic id `@+id/android:empty`, so this TextView will only be visible when the ListView is empty.  (I have no idea why the EditText isn't shown.)  Are you calling `setContentView()` with this layout?

Comment: @Sam I have copied and pasted the above layout, Everything is visible...may be ha hasn't set ContentView in the Activity as you said

Comment: @Pragnani I agree, the layout is ok, I just doubt it's being used. I posted an answer explaining why oonly the ListView is visible.

Answer (score 1):

> I fill ListView ... But textView and Edit Text are not visibile.

If you can only see a ListView then it appears you're using a ListActivity and forgot to call `setContentView()`.  So you aren't actually using your layout... you only see ListActivity's default ListView.

---

That said, your XML code will work, but here are some quick notes:

1. As I stated in my comment, the TextView might be hidden depending on what type of Activity or Fragment you are using:

   - A ListActivity will automatically bind the `@+id/android:empty` and `@+id/android:list` Views, so the "empty" TextView is only shown when the ListView is empty.
   - An Activity won't recognize `@+id/android:empty` on its own.  All the Views should be visible.
2. `fill_parent` is deprecated, simply use `match_parent`
3. Setting a ListView's height to `wrap_content` forces the Adapter to draw the ListView multiple times... with your layout I recommend using `match_parent`.

Answer (score -1):

I'd say it **is** visible pretty fine with your layout. But anyway, I'd make listview declared that way:

```
<ListView
   android:id="@+id/android:list"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="0dp"
   android:layout_weight="1" >
```

so it will take all the **remaining** free space